# Can't add languages to my app

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6, xcode7, localizable.strings

I'd like to add a 2nd language to my app. If I go to my project und press the + under `Localizations` I can select a langue but can't go further (no files are displayed). If I click finish the language isn't added.

Comment: The scope of your question sounds like it could be fairly broad. Have you localized your strings? If you're looking for a step-by-step guide, I highly recommend Stanford's CS193P Lecture 17. Here's the page for the projects to follow along http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/423 and here's the URL for the lecture itself. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w_ESzTD7YA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you don't have any localizable file ? Or Xcode didn't find them...
Anyway, you can always localize files manually :

- Select your file in the left panel
- Open the right panel in the "File Inspector" tab (first icon at the top)
- Click the "Localize" button
- Try again to add a language